# GeoDjango Heroku Buildpack Error: GEOS not detected

Tags: django, heroku, geodjango

I'm using [GeoDjango](https://github.com/dulaccc/heroku-buildpack-geodjango) buildpack for Heroku and keep having an issue that I can't solve and am going around in circles. I was hoping someone can help.

App seems to build ok:

```
Counting objects: 4, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (4/4), done.
Writing objects: 100% (4/4), 356 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 4 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:        Using geos version: 3.4.2
remote:        Installed
remote:        GEOS installed and accessible with env variable 'GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH'
remote:        Using proj version: 4.8.0_1
remote:        Installed
remote:        Proj.4 installed and accessible with env variable 'PROJ4_LIBRARY_PATH'
remote:        Using gdal version: 1.11.1
remote:        Installed
remote:        GDAL installed and accessible with env variable 'GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH'
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with pip
remote: You are using pip version 7.0.1, however version 7.1.2 is available.
remote: You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
remote: 
remote: -----> Preparing static assets
remote:        Collectstatic configuration error. To debug, run:
remote:        $ heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote: 
remote: -----> Discovering process types
remote:        Procfile declares types -> web
remote: 
remote: -----> Compressing... done, 141.3MB
remote: -----> Launching... done, v33
```

But the issue arrises when I change the model file and then try to run:

```
heroku run python manage.py syncdb
```

I'm getting an error:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: GEOS is required and has not been detected. Are you sure it is installed?
```

My settings file contains:

```
GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GEOS_LIBRARY_PATH')
GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH = environ.get('GDAL_LIBRARY_PATH')
```

I’m relatively new to Django and Heroku, is there something obvious I’m doing wrong? I suspect it might be a path issue, but I'm not sure how to resolve it.

Many thanks

Comment: Doing the environ get lines like you did actually worked for me. Likely there is a failure somewhere up the chain. Sorry that I can't verify better for you. Did you end up solving this?